# Computing p-value of LM statistic value in Stata

Tags: stata, p-value

Do you know how can I compute out the p-value in LM statistics? (What is the command in stata?)
I know that to implement the LM computing procedure I have to do the following steps:

1. Obtain the OLS estimators of the restricted model;
2. Obtain the residuals regression;
3. regress the residuals on all independent variablesof the unrestricted model;
4. get the R^2 of this regression;
5. get LM stat that is [R^2] * [# of observations];

I know how I have to proceed till now, but how can I compute out the p-value for the LM statistics? Does somebody know how getting the solution?
Thanks in advance for helping!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_test) in wikipedia,

> This [the LM statistics] follows a chi-squared distribution, with degrees of freedom equal to the number of estimated parameters (in the auxiliary regression) minus one.

A rapid inspection of the original article of [White (1980)](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1912934) confirms this (eq. 2, eq. 3, and Corollary 1 in the article should be what you are looking for).

Comment: White's test is pre-programmed in Stata as `estat imtest, white`. See http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?regress%20postestimation (search page for 'White')

Comment: I solved my problem; anyway thank you for your interest and for helping afresh! In any case, I needed for the LM statistics p-value that one can compute out by texting on stata command: display chi2tail(q;n*R^2). Thank you agin man!

Comment: I has been a while since my last time working in stata but I think this [link](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?pchi) may be useful for you.